# Executing a command within powershell with newlines in arguments

Tags: powershell

Below is a powershell script I am trying to get working. Its designed to run with GitHub for Windows git shell and I have am trying to call "Hub" (https://github.com/github/hub), but thats not relevant. I can call it fine except in one of the command line parameters I  want to have some newlines. Is there some way to do this? The new lines are being interpreted as the end of the command.

The newlines are the $msg variable. So the (abbreviated) output is something like:

```
hub pull-request -m "PFR-1

https://linktoitem/PFR-1
"
```

But the command line just sees: hub pull-request -m "PFR-1

```
$branch = $Global:GitStatus.branch
$segments = $branch.split("/")

iex "git push -u origin $branch"

if ($segments.Length -eq 2 -and $segments[1] -match "^\w+\-\d+$") 
{
    $jiraItem = $segments[1].ToUpper()
    $msg =  "$jiraItem`r`n``r`nnhttps://someurl.atlassian.net/browse/$jiraItem"
    echo "hub pull-request -m ""$msg"" -b kiandra-projects:develop -h kiandra-projects:$branch"
    iex "& hub pull-request -m ""$msg"" -b kiandra-projects:develop -h kiandra-projects:$branch"
}
else
{
    iex "hub pull-request -b kiandra-projects:develop -h kiandra-projects:$branch"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a here-string?

```
$MultilineString = @"
Stuff
More stuff
"@

# in your case:

$msg = @"
$jiraItem

https://someurl.atlassian.net/browse/$jiraItem
"@
```

Note: The closing `"@` must be on its own line

Also, check http://chocolatey.org/packages/Posh-GitHub, it may do what you need

Comment: Thanks buts the problem isn't creating a string with newlines in it. The problem is making the command line interpreter read the newlines as part of the argument value rather than the end of the command. Github for windows powershell has posh github in it - its not really relevant to my issue.

Comment: have you tried it without the iex, and just calling "hub" directly?

Comment: The module is an API for working with github. If I understand your commands correctly, the equivalent would be `New-GitHubPullRequest -b kiandra-projects:develop -h kiandra-projects:$branch -body:$msg`

Comment: I tried calling hub directly with the same result. I'm sorry I thought u meant posh-git and this is (obviously) something else! Looks like it could do the job. Thanks, but forgetting about git for a second I want to know if there is a way to have new lines in command arguments

Comment: I usually fall back onto .NET Process.Start for complex arguments. In more recent versions of powershell argument splatting might work, but I haven't tested it with external programs.

Comment: Yes I think it is my need to call an external program that is screwing me over.